# ARKit Animation Not Anchoring

Tags: swift, animation, arkit

I have a simple jumping animation that I am trying to display in AR with ARKit.

It generally works, but I'm having some translation and anchoring issues.

[This video](https://youtu.be/T6xdOVqgs6Y) demonstrates the problem. The character moves with the camera, rather than staying anchored while the camera moves around it.

I have very little experience with AR, ARKit, and animation in general (I am a developer), and am wondering if anyone can identify some obvious issues that might be a root cause of this problem.

Comment: Have you implemented an `ARPlaneAnchor`, and used that as a plane to place your objects on?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my model was huge relative to the world space- like a kilometer tall, but also a kilometer away from the camera. So you could pan properly, but of course moving a few meters forward and backward didn't appear to have an effect.

Scaled my model down to 0.1% and everything is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a tracking problem - do you add the model only once tracking has been initialised?

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

    if let state = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.trackingState {
        switch(state) {
        case .normal:

        // tracking is ready - add your model now.

        case .notAvailable:
            break
        case .limited(let _):
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Try using

```
self.sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints, ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin]
```

in your `viewWillAppear()` method. If you don't see any feature points (or it doesn't look like they're tracking very well) then you know that that is the problem.

Also if the world origin (the multi-coloured lines) seem to move around too then it is definitely the tracking.

The only way to rectify this is to use a spot that's better lit and has more features. And also wait for a bit longer before placing the model so that tracking has a better chance of becoming stable.